# shell script to add a new column at last

Tags: shell, unix, csv, awk

```
Input file test.csv 
=================
1,abc, 12,12-19
2,aslk,16,13-143
3,kjsd,45,11-137
4,ajsd,144,10-190

required output:
======================== 
1,abc, 12,12-19,z
2,aslk,16,13-143,z
3,kjsd,45,11-137,z
4,ajsd,144,10-190,z
```

I am using  the following command.

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$5="z"; print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

but I am getting:

```
========================
1,abc, 12,12-19
,z
2,aslk,16,13-143
,z
3,kjsd,45,11-137
,z
4,ajsd,144,10-190
,z
```

Please help me to get the required output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {print $0, "z"}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Or even simpler to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/,z/' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: If am using this then I am getting same result. and if I opening this using 'vi' editor then I am getting '^M' symbol before ',z'   :(

Comment: That means you have `\r` like Windows file. Use this awk: `awk -v RS='\r\n' 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {print $0, "z"}' input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: Depending on your environment you might need to use gawk with `-v BINMODE=3` if you want to include the control-Ms in the RS.

Answer (score 1):

Your input file contains control-Ms, provided absolutely free by some Windows program. To get rid of them run dos2unix or similar on your file first and then run your awk script.

Comment: Hey Ed, Thanks, Yes our file is .csv made through SAS, and we are using it in Linux. But Anubhava's one line code worked for out requirement. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

**With sed:**

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ sed 's/$/,z/g' input.csv > output.csv
1,abc, 12,12-19,z
2,aslk,16,13-143,z
3,kjsd,45,11-137,z
4,ajsd,144,10-190,z
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ z=25; sed "s/$/,$z/g" input.csv > output.csv
1,abc, 12,12-19,25
2,aslk,16,13-143,25
3,kjsd,45,11-137,25
4,ajsd,144,10-190,25
```

**With awk:**

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ awk 'sub(/$/,",z")' input.csv > output.csv
1,abc, 12,12-19,z
2,aslk,16,13-143,z
3,kjsd,45,11-137,z
4,ajsd,144,10-190,z
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ awk -v z="25" '{sub(/$/,","z)} {print}' input.csv > output.csv
1,abc, 12,12-19,25
2,aslk,16,13-143,25
3,kjsd,45,11-137,25
4,ajsd,144,10-190,25
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short simple `awk`

```
awk '$0=$0",z"' file
1,abc, 12,12-19,z
2,aslk,16,13-143,z
3,kjsd,45,11-137,z
4,ajsd,144,10-190,z
```